# Cannot get a reference to my Service instance to successfully pass it a handler

Tags: android, service, background

I'm continuing to inch my way forward on this Service example (page 304) of [Pro Android 2](http://www.apress.com/9781430226598) Again, the Service example consists of two classes: MainActivity.java and BackgroundService.java both shown below. My latest hurdle is getting and using a reference to a Service instance to successfully pass it a handler.

From web searches I have found ugly ways to pass a handler to a Service instance that just don't work. I would appreciate some help on my next step in this process - making it work. Please have a look at my comments and code below that document my attempt to pass a handler to a Service instance in the bind button (bindBtn).

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Log.d(TAG, "starting service");

            Button bindBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bindBtn);
            bindBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent backgroundService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.marie.mainactivity.BackgroundService.class);
                    startService(backgroundService);

                    // wait until BackgroundService has started
                    while (BackgroundService.getInstance() == null);
                    // get instance of BackgroundService
                    BackgroundService sInstance = BackgroundService.getInstance();

                    // now finally pass the handler to the Service              
                    sInstance.setHandler(handler);
                }
            });

            Button unbindBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.unbindBtn);
            unbindBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // The handler to be passed to the Service
    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String msgObj = (String) msg.obj;
            int arg1 = msg.arg1;
            int arg2 = msg.arg2;
            int what = msg.what;
            Log.i("handleMessge", "msgObj: " + msgObj + ", " + "arg1: " + arg1 + ", " + "arg2: " + arg2 + ", " + "what: " + what);  
        }
    };
```

And now the BackgroundService:

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
        private NotificationManager notificationMgr;

        private Handler mHandler;
        private static Service sInstance = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            notificationMgr = NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            displayNotificationMessage("starting Background Service");

            Thread thr = new Thread(null, new ServiceWorker(), "BackgroundService");
            thr.start();
        }   

        class ServiceWorker implements Runnable
        {
            public void run() {
                //Use the handler to send a message
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "msg obj";
                msg.arg1 = 1;
                msg.arg2 = 2;
                msg.what = 3;
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                //stop when done
                BackgroundService.this.stopSelf();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            displayNotificationMessage("stopping Background Service");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        private void displayNotificationMessage(String message)
        {
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.note, message, System.currentTimeMillis());

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Background Service", message, contentIntent);

            notificationMgr.notify(R.id.app_notification_id, notification);
        }
    }
```

My goal is to pass a handler to the Service after binding to it with the bind button (bindBtn) and send a message to the handler. But I get an ANR: ERROR/ActivityManager(96): ANR in com.marie.mainactivity. So clearly this seems to be the wrong way to pass a handler to a Service as it does not work.

I'm attempting to post the Logcat of the ANR below:

```
D/MainActivity(24622): starting service

I/ActivityManager(   96): Displayed com.marie.mainactivity/.MainActivity: +434ms

D/dalvikvm(23879): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 50% free 2740K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 79ms

D/dalvikvm(18736): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 49% free 2793K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 740ms

D/dalvikvm(18551): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 49% free 2967K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 583ms

D/dalvikvm(  192): GC_EXPLICIT freed 42K, 53% free 3950K/8327K, external 12167K/12379K, paused 1000ms

W/ActivityManager(   96): Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{4078d160 com.marie.mainactivity/.BackgroundService}

I/Process (   96): Sending signal. PID: 24622 SIG: 3

I/dalvikvm(24622): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3

I/dalvikvm(24622): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process (   96): Sending signal. PID: 96 SIG: 3

I/dalvikvm(   96): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3

I/dalvikvm(   96): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process (   96): Sending signal. PID: 184 SIG: 3

I/dalvikvm(  184): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3

I/dalvikvm(  184): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process (   96): Sending signal. PID: 158 SIG: 3

I/dalvikvm(  158): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3

I/dalvikvm(  158): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

D/dalvikvm(   96): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1045K, 41% free 6408K/10759K, external 2855K/3554K, paused 126ms

E/ActivityManager(   96): ANR in com.marie.mainactivity

E/ActivityManager(   96): Reason: Executing service com.marie.mainactivity/.BackgroundService

E/ActivityManager(   96): Load: 2.86 / 2.27 / 1.69

E/ActivityManager(   96): CPU usage from 20840ms to 0ms ago:

E/ActivityManager(   96):   93% 24622/com.marie.mainactivity: 93% user + 0% kernel / faults: 536 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   1.4% 73/akmd: 0% user + 1.4% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0.5% 96/system_server: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 9 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0.1% 23879/com.google.android.apps.uploader: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0.1% 192/com.android.launcher: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 69 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0.1% 18551/android.process.acore: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 54 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0.1% 18736/android.process.media: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0% 158/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0% 5/events/0: 0% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0% 48/synaptics_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   0% 56/ds2784-battery: 0% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96): 96% TOTAL: 96% user + 0.3% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96): CPU usage from 378ms to 893ms later:

E/ActivityManager(   96):   94% 24622/com.marie.mainactivity: 94% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):     94% 24622/ie.mainactivity: 94% user + 0% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   3.8% 96/system_server: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):     3.8% 115/ActivityManager: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):   1.3% 73/akmd: 0% user + 1.3% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96):     1.3% 24209/akmd: 0% user + 1.3% kernel

E/ActivityManager(   96): 100% TOTAL: 98% user + 1.9% kernel

I/Process (   96): Sending signal. PID: 24622 SIG: 9

W/ActivityManager(   96):   Force finishing activity com.marie.mainactivity/.MainActivity

I/ActivityManager(   96): Killing com.marie.mainactivity (pid=24622): user's request

I/ActivityManager(   96): Process com.marie.mainactivity (pid 24622) has died.

W/ActivityManager(   96): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{4078d160 com.marie.mainactivity/.BackgroundService}

I/WindowManager(   96): WIN DEATH: Window{407b7a70 com.marie.mainactivity/com.marie.mainactivity.MainActivity paused=true}

V/RenderScript_jni(  192): surfaceCreated

V/RenderScript_jni(  192): surfaceChanged

W/InputManagerService(   96): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 24622 uid 10081

I/ActivityManager(   96): Start proc com.amazon.mp3 for service com.amazon.mp3/.service.DownloadService: pid=24632 uid=10055 gids={3003, 1015}

I/ActivityThread(24632): Pub com.amazon.mp3.client.SearchSuggestionProvider: com.amazon.mp3.client.SearchSuggestionProvider

D/Configuration(24632): active site = local

D/FREESPACE(24632): Bytes to fill: 107900928

D/Configuration(24632): active site = remote

I/Gmail   (24587): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing

I/Gmail   (24587): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running

I/Gmail   (24587): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 687539, normalSync: true

D/dalvikvm(24587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1165K, 54% free 3133K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3ms+4ms

D/dalvikvm(24587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 617K, 55% free 3081K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 11ms+2ms

D/dalvikvm(24587): GC_EXPLICIT freed 160K, 55% free 3083K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 54ms

I/Gmail   (24587): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 687616, normalSync: true

D/Gmail   (24587): Inserting message 1371513932623117837. synced=true

D/dalvikvm(24587): GC_EXPLICIT freed 123K, 54% free 3127K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 63ms

I/Gmail   (24587): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 687618, normalSync: true

I/Gmail   (24587): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^i (has extras) }

I/AudioService(   96):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@4074e410

W/AudioFlinger(   68): write blocked for 167 msecs, 27 delayed writes, thread 0xea00

I/AudioService(   96):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@4074e410

D/AudioHardwareQSD(   68): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.

D/dalvikvm(24587): GC_EXPLICIT freed 88K, 54% free 3138K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 98ms

I/ActivityManager(   96): Start proc org.my_pod.mypod for service org.my_pod.mypod/net.robmunro.mypod.UpdateFeedsService: pid=24654 uid=10080 gids={3003, 1015}

D/dalvikvm(   67): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 50% free 2717K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 68ms

D/dalvikvm(   67): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2717K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 63ms

I/ActivityThread(24654): Pub org.my_pod.mypod: net.robmunro.mypod.util.MyPodContentProvider

D/dalvikvm(   67): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2717K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 74ms
```

Any advice with what I am doing wrong creating a *Service instance* so I can pass it things like a handler would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In cae of ANr always post Logcat. :)

Comment: @Saurabh I am trying to post the Logcat now. I think it's long. Does posting it work like posting code?

Comment: @Saurabh I added what I felt was the relevant part of the logcat from where it says starting service until the ANR occurs which I FORCE CLOSE. But it seems much too long. If anyone knows how to edit the logcat so it uses scroll bars like code does I would appreciate it.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for putting scroll bars on my logcat post! Please tell me how you did it. Did you take it into an editor like Gvim and indent the whole block by eight spaces?

Comment: When you are editing a question or answer (but not a comment), you will see a toolbar above the text area. Highlight source code or a LogCat listing and press the {} icon. This indents everything by four spaces, which in Markdown (the wikitext format used by StackOverflow) will cause it to be formatted as source code. A side effect is that it adds the scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend passing a `Messenger` to the service and using it to send a `Message` to the `Handler`. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader) demonstrating this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was advised by @Femi "when you get the Service instance you can pass it a Handler." But I will definitely look at your sample application. It seems my biggest problem is I don't know how to get a reference to the Service instance (I should change the title of my question to that) - I cannot pass _anything_ to the Service. By the way @Saurabh suggested I post the logcat with the ANR but it's long. Do you know how to post it like code with scroll bars? I think my question is too long now.

Comment: @Marie: Since you are using `startService()`, package the `Messenger` as an `Intent` extra.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes thank you! I understand now. I also looked at this method "public void doTheDownload(View v)" in your sample application. It clearly shows how to use i.putExtra() to pass the Messenger() when calling startService(i). I'd seen putExtra() before but just did not make the connection. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the title of my question to reflect better the error in my thinking and to help others with the same confusion. Your sample application completely solved my problem, but why doesn't i.putExtra(MyService.EXTRA_HANDLER, myHandler) work?

Comment: @Marie: Because `Handler` does not implement the `Parcelable` interface. It is not designed to be passed between components.

Comment: @CommonsWare the sample application you pointed me was great! Thank you! It got me going with at least one handler. Is this sample extendable to have more than one activity use it and each pass it their own handler?

Comment: @Marie: I have not tried multiple `Handler`s in an application, so I do not know if that will work or not, but it is certainly worth trying.

Comment: Why is communicating with a Messenger recommended instead of through Handlers (besides that a Handler doesn't communicate Messages between two different processes)? I assume that when you are running your activities and services in the same process, it is better and faster to communicate between these two using Handlers and not Messengers? If I am not mistaken, Messengers are a sort of wrapper around the Handlers so inter process communication can be archieved. Why not startService, bind to service with local binder, store the service Handler in global memory, use this handler in all activity?

Comment: @user504342: "Why is communicating with a Messenger recommended instead of through Handlers" -- because a `Handler` is not `Parcelable` and cannot be passed in an `Intent` with `startService()`. "Why not startService, bind to service with local binder, store the service Handler in global memory, use this handler in all activity?" -- first, you do not normally need to use both `startService()` and `bindService()`. Second, you are leaking memory with your "global memory" `Handler`. Third, if you are binding, you do not need either a `Handler` *or* a `Messenger` -- use your own listener.

Comment: @CommonsWare "you do not normally need to use both startService() and bindService()", I am missing an essential part here. I now use both in my App: first activity starts service, next activity binds to service to get handler not messenger of service (local binder used). No correct use? Second: how else do I get the handler from the service if I do not bind to it to get the handler? I have pass the service handler from activity to activity, or is there a better way? Third: listener? Please explain...

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe it is a good idea to continue under [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608400/handler-to-handler-versus-messenger-to-messenger-communication-in-android) question and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541290/getting-a-handler-from-a-thread-from-service-to-activity/) question? I am struggling with getting it "right" in my head. I need async comm. between activities and service, without needlessly binding to the service and best performance throughput. Using a Listener sounds faster...