# Getting a Handler from a Thread from Service to Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, handler

Situation:

1. activity binds to started foreground service.
2. service hands out local binder to activity.
3. activity gets reference to service through a getService() call.
4. activity wants to communicate **directly** with a thread running in the service using messages. It calls the mService.getThreadHandler() method from the activity.

Problem:

- how do I get a Handler from the current running thread into the active activity, so that I can post messages directly to the threads messagequeue?

I don't what to use a messenger within the service, I want to directly communicate with the thread in the service from the activity side.

**Edit:** the activity gets the handler of the thread itself in the service, by calling something like this:

Activity code:

```
Handler mServiceThreadHandler;
ServiceConnection mServiceConnection;

public void onStart() {
  if (!bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), mServiceConnection,    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) 
  {
    Log.e(TAG, "Client did not bind to Service!");
  } 
  super.onStart();
}

public class MyLocalServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = (MainService) binder.getService();
                    // the handler of the service is actually a handler of a thread
                    // within the service, and is set automatically within the binding
                    // activity when binding to the service. That way you have a direct
                    // "connection" with the message queue of the thread instead of
                    // a message queue in the service itself (main thread of service)
        mServiceThreadHandler = mService.getServiceHandler();

        if (mServiceThreadHandler == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Service handler is NULL");
        }
        mBoundedToService = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServiceThreadHandler = null;
        mBoundedToService = false;
    }
}
```

Service code:

```
private HandlerThread mServiceThread = new MyServiceThread();

public Handler getServiceHandler() {
    return new Handler(mServiceThread.getLooper());
}
```

Does the **new Handler(mServiceThread.getLooper());** return a new Handler or the same Handler within the mServiceThread?

**Edit 2:** updating the Service code with the serviceThread which receives the messages.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  private MyHandlerThread serviceThread = new MyHandlerThread("serviceThread");

  serviceThread.start();

public Handler getServiceHandler() {
  // hand out the same handler of the service thread for using it in an activity!
  // serviceThread.getLooper() is the current looper of the thread
  // serviceThread is the 'this' which handles the messages (see MyHandlerThread)
  return new Handler(serviceThread.getLooper(), serviceThread); 
}

  // do stuff in Service
}

public class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread implements android.os.Handler.Callback {
public MyHandlerThread(String name) {
    super(name);
}
public MyHandlerThread(String name, int priority) {
    super(name, priority);
}
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO define your own message handling here.
    return false;
}
}
```

Correct?

Comment: Instead of `ThreadHandler`, why don't you simply return the `Handler` via **public method** in `Service`?

Comment: the easiest way is to use a HandlerThread in your Service

Comment: If I use a HandlerThread class, I need to have a getter for fetching the Handler of that class, but I don't see any getters in HandlerThread to fetch a Handler, only a getLooper() which doesn't have a getHandler() method :(

Comment: I am looking at these examples: [link](http://techtej.blogspot.nl/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010607/how-to-initialize-handlers-from-separated-threads) but I can't figure it out to work properly

Comment: ht = new HandlerThread(); ht.start(); h = new Handler(ht.getLooper())

Comment: Does this mean **h = new Handler(ht.getLooper());** that the same handler is returned that is contained within the thread? If so, where do I define the handleMessage() method of the Handler for my custom message handling within the thread itself? I need the Handler for to things: for handling the messages from the activity to the service (therefore I need a copy of the thread Handler, otherwise I can't sent messages to it) and for defining how to handle the messages within the service thread itself. I am confused :(

Comment: 3 options: with the code i already sent you can h.post(Runnable), 2 use new Handler(Looper, Callback), 3 extend Handler and override handleMessage()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39834/discussion-between-user504342-and-pskink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (i used Activity to test it you will use Service):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ht = new HandlerThread("HT");
    ht.start();
    htHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper(), htCallback);
    mainHandler = new Handler(mainCallback);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        htHandler.sendMessageDelayed(htHandler.obtainMessage(99, i, 0), i * 3000);
    }
}

private HandlerThread ht;
private Handler htHandler;
private Handler mainHandler;

private Callback htCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage **********************");
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage " + msg);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        if (msg.arg1 == 4) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage sending back to Main thread");
            mainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(101);
        }
        return false;
    }
}; 

private Callback mainCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage ########################");
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage " + msg);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage i'm quitting");
        ht.quit();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: No!!! "this" has to implement Callback, see how Handler is created (second param)

Comment: I get it: MyActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback; or MyService extends Service implements Handler.Callback; On the activity side I understand, not on the Service side, because the HandlerThread must be the one who implements Handler.Callback, right?

Comment: your first guess was correct: MyService extends Service
implements Handler.Callback;

Comment: I think I finally got it: the 'this' is where you handle the message, and the new Handler(ht.getLooper(), this); only tells the handler where the actual message is handled. That is a bit confusing, because normally you hand over or define a Handler that you give as a parameter to a method call. Now the parameter is not the actual Handler but the place where it is handled.

Comment: exactly, and it is imho convienient as you dont have to create any new classes extending Handler

Comment: See my updated edit2 in question. You are right about not needlessly extending the Handler class, but the HandlerThread must be extended otherwise I don't have a default Looper in my thread, correct?

Comment: no need to extend HandlerThread, just implement a Callback, create one handler that you pass to clients and thats it

Comment: The **new Handler(mServiceThread.getLooper(), this)** in combination with the Handler.Callback interface on the service side means I have to implement the handleMessage() in the Service object, not on the HandlerThread (= mServiceThread). This is not what I want. I want to be able to distinguish messages that are sent from the activity directly to the servicethread and messages sent from the service to the servicethread, because the service code can also sent a command to the thread (when exiting the service I send a stop message to the thread).

Comment: ... if you implement it like this, I cannot distinguish messages intended for the thread and messages intended for the service (sent back from thread to let the service know it can stop now). There are four sorts of messagesflows: activity2servicethread, servicethread2service, service2servicethread and servicethread2activity.

Comment: so create another Handler: serviceHandler = new
Handler(this); it has a Looper that works on service(ui) thread so you can send messages to/from HT and whats interesting handle them using the same Callback!

Comment: That's the point: I do not want to use the same Callback, serviceHandler is NOT equal to ThreadHandler. That way I can write the code precisely: only switch on msg-types that are for service and only switch on msg-types that are for servicethread (not in the same handleMessage code). Also send msg from thread2service (going from service-thread to main-thread and vise versa). I understand the service call back idea, not how you "inject" or define a Handler within the Thread without subclassing HandlerThread. I am missing a valueable puzzlepiece here, I guess.

Comment: Last question for today: see javadoc for ht.quit(). I can change it into quitSafely() but it requires apilevel=18. So, can't use that. This means unsafe "quiting". I think it's better if I extend a HandlerThread and override handleMessage() there and also override run() method. In the handleMessage I can set a boolean to false that is causing the run() method to exit normally: run() { while(!cancelled) { // do stuff and handle the messages } }. This would also be a better choice when I also need to communicate between the servicethread and childernThreads within the serviceThread.

Comment: Another thing is the **mainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(101);** in htCallback: you could set the "target" field in each message (using setTarget()), so that the receiving party knows where to send the reply message (reply-handler). That means that you do not have to set a fixed reference to the other handler in each handler, because you send the reference of the other handler within the message. At least, that is what I make out of the javadocs. See #setTarget(Handler target)

Comment: extending HandlerThread and overriding handleMessage() is needless since HandlerThread has no such method :(

its run() method has only (mor or less): looper.prepare() followed by looper.loop() so i dont know what you would like to override here. safelyQuit() differs from quit() only in that it dispatches all pending Messages while quit() just quits removig all of them, see the sources how its done.

Comment: setTarget() is not an envelope label saying: "if want to reply to my mail i am john smith living in [address here]"
when you try to call msg.getTarget() in htCallback you will see that getTarget() is always == htHandler, the same for mainCallback: getTarget() is always == mainHandler

Comment: Oops, you're correct. I was misguided by the Messenger replyTo field within Message class. But using a Messenger is more resource intensive than a Handler directly. It seems you cannot put another Handler into the message telling the other side what the return Handler address is. I thought that was the case with setHandler, but that - indeed - sets the current handler again :(  Maybe add a replyTo Handler with the setData(Bundle) method could be an option?

Comment: they say that setData is a last resort and you should use arg0, arg1 and obj so you can use arg0 as an index to Handler[] keeping reply-to Handler

Comment: So, I use the Message msg.obj = this; when I want the serviceThread to reply to the activity (=this) and I use Message msg.obj = htHandler; (= handler of thread) when I want the activity to reply to my service. Or even better, I don't have to tell the activity what the reply address is because the service handler is handed out by the ServiceConnection object to the activity at binding. Between threads, I DO need to tell what the reply address is, because there is no other way to tell which message came from which thread (assuming 1 thread received more msgs from different threads), right?

Comment: right, Message has no "sender" data so you have to keep track of that

Comment: Great! This question is answered in detail. Thanks pskink! I'll update the final solution in the original question later today. This is a great solution because it cuts down on overhead in communication between activity/service, service/thread, activity/thread and thread/thread. Before I used Messengers between activity/service (=overkill).

Comment: forgot to mention to always call #recycle() when you have handled the message in your handleMessage method. The message is then returned to the message pool of 'free to re-use' messages. Do NOT use msg object after you called recycle!

Comment: fortunatelly no need for manual recycle: see Looper.loop() sources

Comment: Nice! I see that #loop() indeed does call msg.recycle(). Is there a relation between the loop() method of Looper and the handleMessage() method of Handler.Callback because the handleMessage() method does return a boolean. Returning true means that the msg is handled in this handleMessage() method and thus can Looper.loop() safely recylce it? In the 'normal' handleMessage() method there is no return value. If your message isn't handled in your own handleMessage() method it has to be passed to the super.handleMessage() method. How does the loop() method know it can recylce this msg?

Comment: see what #loop() does with msg: msg .target .
dispatchMessage (msg );

Comment: If I understand correctly: msg.callback == this of activity with handler.Callback implemented --> dispatchMessage() runs/executes the msg. If callback missing (no 'this', no object) then inherited method of custom Handler class gets the opportunity to process its msg?? My head is spinning of this code ;)

Comment: msg.callback is used when posting Runnables, for Handler.Callback mechanism see that if (mCallback !=
null) {

Comment: aha! in the 'else' of the dispatchMessage, it looks if it should handle a callback implementation of handleMessage or a derived implementation of handleMessage.

Comment: My brain just rebooted: htCallback == This is the handler of the thread running within the service (defined within the service, executed in the thread itself); mainCallback == This is the handler of the service itself (defined within the service, executed within the service = main/ui=thread). Shouldn't both callbacks return true if the message was handled here?

Comment: yes you should return true drom Callback.handleMessage, but if you return false nothing bad happens as empty Handler.handleMessage will be called

Comment: pskink, could you please also look at this question? See: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568388/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-android-service-with-threads-running-in-the-service). Its a follow up of this question. Thanks!